# Pass drop down list value from jsp to spring controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Given the following code:

```
@Controller  
public class Foo  
{  
    public void foo(@RequestParam("dropDown") String value)  
    {
           ...
    }  
}
```

and a jsp:

```
<div>   
    <form action="/foo">  
      <select id="dropDown">
            <option value="bar">bar</option>

     </select>
    </form>   
</div>
```

How can I pass back the value that gets selected in the `dropDown` id back to my Spring controller?  As it stands I get invalid request parameters when I attempt ot execute this.

Comment: the <select> needs a `name` - http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select

Comment: @bmorris591 care to share a working solution?

Comment: What he means is `<select name="dropDown">` instead of what you have. This however will only give you the value in the `value` attribute of the `<option>` element.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis right that is what I want, but it does not give me a value out of the request.

Comment: According to your pasted code everything looks fine. Probably you are missing something else.

Comment: @Woot4Moo If you change `id` attribute to `name` it works. You must be missing the `@RequestMapping` or `action="/foo"` might not be relative to your context root.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis will test when I return home

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>   
    <form action="/foo">  
      <select name="dropDown">
            <option value="bar">bar</option>

     </select>
    </form>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the @RequestMapping annotations set up in your controller, so that submitted form is returned to the correct method? In this case, you'd want:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

On your `foo()` method, I think.

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch16s11.html for more information.